# What does 通常進行 mean in the context of a two week serialized mangaka job?

Tags: kanji, compounds, interpretation

I can understand both words separately, and even together in some specific contexts. I can't understand the meaning of these two together in the following phrase and context:

> 「締切りを３日早めてほしいの。それでようやく通常進行に戻るのよ」

The author is a mangaka, with a serialization of 1 chapter per 2 weeks. The editor asks her to anticipate the deadline by three days, so she could go back to 通常進行.

> 通常
>   1. usual; ordinary; normal; regular; general; common​

> 進行
>   1. moving forward (e.g. vehicle); onward movement​
>   2. advance (work, procedure, etc); advancement; progress​
>   3. progress (of a disease); disease progression​
>   4. progression (harmonic, melodic)​Music term

Comment: Sounds like you've answered it yourself just by typing it out, no?

Comment: I think not... I can see the idea of "normal progress" in some works like when you're behind schedule or something, but not when that is not the case. The serialization is 1 chapter per 2 weeks, which is already the case in the context (they're not behind schedule). I asked because I thought that maybe it has some other interpretation or meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

進行 in a project managing context roughly means "schedule", "scheduling" or "managing". 進行 also refers to a kind of manager whose main responsibility is keeping tasks on schedule. ([アニメの制作進行](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C%E9%80%B2%E8%A1%8C) is known as one of the toughest jobs.)

通常進行 here means "regular schedule" or "normal cycle" of the bimonthly publishing. The editor is saying the mangaka's deadlines for the recent issues has been delayed for three days, and she wants to return to the regular cycle.